# Pdo insert problems

Tags: php, pdo

Good day everyone!
Why is that everytime I try to insert something that has the same 'sid' with the one which is already insert, It won't insert into the db.

e.g 1st insert = sid: 1 , sname: cat, title: the giver

2nd insert = sid: 1 , sname: cat, title: fangirl <-- the 2nd insert won't insert as another item on the db. I didn't even tried placing any conditions about it.

What seems to be the cause of this problem? And one more thing, When I try to select all the items on its table, It would only show the up to four items. When there would be a new entry, It would replace the older ones and still im not placing any conditions on such things.

**For the show function:**

```
public function showData($table)
    {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $stmt = $this->con->query($q);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

**For the insert function:**

```
    public function insertbookborrow($sid,$sname,$title,$author,$isbn,$publisher,$language,$genre,$borrow_date,$return_date,$table)
    {
      $q = "INSERT INTO $table SET sid=:sid,sname=:sname,title=:title,author=:author,isbn=:isbn,publisher=:publisher,language=:language, genre=:genre,borrow_date=:borrow_date, return_date=:return_date";
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
      $stmt->execute(array(':sid'=>$sid,':sname'=>$sname,':title'=>$title,':author'=>$author,':isbn'=>$isbn,':publisher'=>$publisher,':language'=>$language,':genre'=>$genre,':borrow_date'=>$borrow_date,':return_date'=>$return_date));
      if($stmt){
            return true;
            }
          else {
              return false;
          }
    }
```

**For the process part**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once "dbconnection.php";

    function __autoload($class){
    include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}

  $code = new books();

  $sname = $_POST['sname'];
  $sid = $_POST['sid'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $author = $_POST['author'];
  $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
  $publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
  $language = $_POST['language'];
  $genre = $_POST['genre'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $borrow_date = $_POST['borrow_date'];
  $return_date = $_POST['return_date'];

  $result = $code->bookreserve($id,"book_info");

  if(isset($_POST['borrow']))
  {
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
          $oldstock=$row['quantity']; 
          if ($oldstock<1) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No more books left to be reserved.');window.location='bookBorrowlist.php';</script>";
          }
          else
          {
            try{
                  $code->minusbookreserve($quantity,$id,"book_info");
                  $code->insertbookborrow($sid,$sname,$title,$author,$isbn,$publisher,$language,$genre,$borrow_date,$return_date,"borrow_list");

                  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  alert('You may check out the book. Overdue fine = 5 php / day.');
                  window.location='bookBorrowlist.php';
                  </script>";

            }catch(PDOException $e)
              {
                  echo $e->getMessage();
              }

          }
      }

  }
  else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something went wrong.');window.location='bookBorrowlist.php';</script>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: learn to **Debug**. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors'); **AND** PDO has Error-Methods, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Assuming `sid` is unique, you can't insert another row with that same value. You're probably looking for [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: It is most likely because the `sid` field is `UNIQUE`. There can only be one row with that value in the table.

Comment: Ahh that's why. Now it's clear to me. Thanks sir. But regarding to my select function, can you state why it's behaving in a way that I won't select or show all the data coming from the table?